# Node.js. Encrypted vs Signed cookies

Tags: node.js, session, encryption, cookies, passport.js

I want to retrieve values from my cookie.

I am using `passport.js`, and In this quest, I have tried different things.

1. I run `req.cookies;` which gives me this:

   ```
   's:x05d6V5Dhf6efFGjIkO26Ka1.imN4lT7OhW83Nc9Z7vw5dFbCoQhanP3aa37iyNWQyvU' }
   ```

   Is this a signed cookie or an encrypted cookie?

   The `'s:'` in the beginning makes it seem like a signed one, however when I ran `req.signedCookies;`, I got back an empty object `{}`. So is this cookie signed or encrypted?

   I then ran: `req.sessionID;` which gave back this:

   ```js
   x05d6V5Dhf6efFGjIkO26Ka1
   ```

   As you can see, this is also contained in my cookie, before the dot. So I guess the `sessionId` is stored in my cookie, right?

   Then I ran `req.secret;` which in turn returned `undefined`.
2. Is the secret in the session, which is declared here:

   ```js
   app.use(express.session({ secret: 'blablablabla' }));
   ```

   used to sign the cookie or to encrypt it?
3. The cookie-signature module can only unsign a cookie and not decrypt them - is that correct?
   It can unsign it based on the previous session secret?
4. Finally, where is this cookie stored? In my mongo db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the dot:

```
imN4lT7OhW83Nc9Z7vw5dFbCoQhanP3aa37iyNWQyvU
```

is the signature of the session id:

```
x05d6V5Dhf6efFGjIkO26Ka1
```

That is to say, the session id is encrypted with the secret and append to the session id with a dot to compose the cookie.

The secret is not contained in the cookie.

The cookie-signature module can unsign a cookie if you provided the right info:

```
cookie-signature.ungisn(`${the_original_sessionid}.${the_encypted_sessionid}`,secret)
```